# Laravel / Eloquent - Difference Between Using toArray() and json_decode to Convert Object to Array

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Sometimes when I need to convert an object I get back from an Eloquent model I use

```
json_decode(json_encode($myObject), false));
```

I've also used

```
$myObject->toArray();
```

I've noticed that the `json_decode` method doesn't work on objects returned from `paginate()`.

What's the difference in implementation between these two methods?

Comment: have you looked at this? https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php it has the function `toArray()`

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that `toArray()` will serialize your nested relationships, only attributes that are visible, it also mutates your attributes and run casts on them.

Something you can check easily by taking a look at the source code for the Eloquent Model, not the Collection. I saved you some time, the code starts [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2255)